# getting error when adding json_serializable

Tags: flutter, freezed, json-serializable

I added json serializabe in my pubspec.yaml and getting below error :

Bad state: Could not parse the options provided for `json_serializable`.
Unrecognized keys: [super-parameters, enhanced-enums]; supported keys: [any_map, checked, constructor, create_factory, create_field_map, create_to_json, disallow_unrecognized_keys, explicit_to_json, field_rename, generic_argument_factories, ignore_unannotated, include_if_null]

my pubsec yaml is

```
environment:
  sdk: ">2.18.0 <3.3.0"
```

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter
flutter_lints: ^1.0.0
freezed: ^2.3.2
build_runner: ^2.1.8
dropdown_search: ^4.0.1
json_serializable: ^6.5.3

When i remove json_serializable from depndency build passes

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to this link https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable/install

You must add `json_serializable` to `dependencies` section. You added it to `dev_dependencies` in the pubspec.yaml file you shared.

Comment: Tried that as well no luck

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation/install can u try adding this package to dependencies and tell me result ?

Comment: your dependencies block must have ```json_serializable``` and ```json_annotation```packages.